# Storing a Map<Locale,String> using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm

What's the simplest way to store a `Map<Locale,String>` attribute using JPA annotations? The application that I'm working on needs to store multilingual text – that is (essentially) the same text but written in multiple languages.

Note that a good number of entities require this kind of attribute (and multiple of such attributes per entity). Therefore the solution needs to be easily replicable and not copy-pasting gobs and gobs of code to each entity.

To illustrate, the application will need to store data for these things:
[image]

(notice that the same item is written in five languages)

Comment: This Answer by @wprecht-ab3ry *is* useful and answers the question (+1 from me). However, if you're creating a productive system, you should avoid one single translation table for all entities. Read this short article for the reason and a hint to a more robust architecture: http://www.beabetterdeveloper.com/2013/04/i18n-of-jpa-entities.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty naive implementation, you'll want to adapt it appropriately to your situation.  But, to make this implementation reusable, you'll want an embeddable class that contains the language -> text mapping.  Then build an entity around that using a hashmap since you'll need things like a unique ID.

```
@Embeddable
public class LocalizedString {

    private String language;
    private String text;

    public LocalizedString() {}

    public LocalizedString(String language, String text) {
        this.language = language;
       this.text = text;
    }

    // auto-generated getters, setters, hashCode(), equals(), etc.
} 



@Entity
@Table(schema = "app", name = "mling_str")
public class MultilingualString {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "string_id")
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "language")
    @CollectionTable(schema = "app", name = "ming_str_map", 
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "string_id"))
    private Map<String, LocalizedString> map = new HashMap<String, LocalizedString>();

    public MultilingualString() {}

    public MultilingualString(String lang, String text) {
        addText(lang, text);
    }

    public void addText(String lang, String text) {
        map.put(lang, new LocalizedString(lang, text));
    }

    public String getText(String lang) {
        if (map.containsKey(lang)) {
           return map.get(lang).getText();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // auto-generated getters, setters, hashCode(), equals(), etc.
}
```